# Same click event for both Button and Grid

Tags: wpf, button, grid, routed-events

I read about Routed events today and tried to provide same click event handler for both a normal button and a custom grid button. Stackpanel is handling the routed button click event, and to invoke same handler I am firing a click event from grid's mousedown event. Code is without error but not working as expected. 
Button click brings the messagebox but clicking the grid with mouse does nothing.

```
<Window x:Class="RoutedEventPr.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="550" Width="525">

<StackPanel  Background="Transparent" Button.Click="Button_Click_1">

    <Grid Width="200" Height="100" Background="Aqua" MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown_1">
        <Ellipse StrokeThickness="4" Width="200" Height="100" Fill="Beige"/>           
        <TextBlock Text="Press" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>

    <Button x:Name="SureBtn" Content="Pause !" Width="200" Margin="0 10 0 0"/>

    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200" Height="200" Source="I://fancybtn.jpg"/>

    <Label Content="Start the game"/>

</StackPanel>
```

```
    private void Grid_MouseDown_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent, this));
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Are you sure !");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Button.Click event**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.click.aspx) is routed event with bubbling strategy set to **`Bubble`**.

That means it will bubble up to visual parent till root until it was handled. In your case, **you raise an event from Window, so it will bubble up from Window to its parent which is null.**

You have to **raise the event from child control of StackPanel so that it can bubble up to StackPanel**.

**XAML**

```
<Grid x:Name="grid" Width="200" Height="100" Background="Aqua" 
      MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown_1">
    <Ellipse StrokeThickness="4" Width="200" Height="100" Fill="Beige"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Press" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

**Code behind**

```
private void Grid_MouseDown_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    grid.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent, this));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did below changes and it works now.

```
private void Grid_MouseDown_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    SureBtn.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent, this));
}
```

Comment: `SureBtn` works because it's child control of StackPanel and hence event bubbles upto parent StackPanel. Check my answer for more details.